# Query a MySQL Database from Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am currently querying a MySQL from Spark as follows:

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val dataframe_mysql = sqlContext
    .read.format("jdbc").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    .option("url", url)
    .option("dbtable", "MyTable")
    .option("user", "MyUser").option("password", "MyPwd")
    .load()

dataframe_mysql.registerTempTable("MyTable")

val lastNames = dataframe_mysql.sqlContext.sql("select lastName from MyTable")
```

But this loads all the columns from the `MyTable`, and I don't need that (I only need the `lastName` column). (moreover, I need a sql join query, and I don't want to load everything into Spark).

How can I replace the `option("dbtable", "MyTable")` line to specify a SQL query instead of a table?

I have tried querying with `.option("dbtable", "select lastName from MyTable")` (as I read somewhere), but this fails with :

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: select lastName from MyTable WHERE 1=0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have read is correct, you'll need to pass the query with pushdown predicates as an option.

MySQL expects here a aliased table or the table fullname :

```
// without pushdown predicates
.option("dbtable", "MyTable")

// with pushdown predicates
.option("dbtable", "(select lastName from MyTable) as T")
```

So you are actually looking to use the later query.

**Note:** `T` can be anything here.